# How to check conditions for every day of a year in loop?

Tags: javascript, datetime, for-loop

I got lot of selected data from fullcalendar. I need to get those selected date from one whole year. How to check that in for loop?
 I tried few answers to add days one by one to my condition from some answers ,but its not working for me.

Here is my code I tried:

```js
  var t=$(#dttbl).datatable();
    var arr = new Array();
    var date = new Date(),
      var Id = 1;
    var d = date.getDate(),
      month = date.getMonth(),
      year = date.getFullYear()
    var day1 = y + '-01-01';
    var day365 = y + '-12-31';
    for (i = day1; i < day365; day1.setdate(day1.getdate() + 1)) {
      if (($(i.cell).css('backgroundColor', 'blue'))) {
        arr.push(([Id,i,'test']));
        Id++;
      }
    }  
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  t.row.add([
   arr[i][0],
   arr[i][1],
  arr[i][2]
   ]).draw();
   }
```

I tried this `getdate()`, `day1.add(1).day();` , `day1=moment(day1).add(1, 'days')` to add one by one day to check my condition for full year? These are not working for me. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why all the ((()))? And where do you update `i` ? You seem to want to increment strings... And what is $(i.cell) supposed to be? Look in the documentation for getting an array of selected dates

Comment: @mplungjan Hi yes, trying to get dates from cell which are blue in color in an array and going to add those in datatable.. Check my question I updated my array related code.

Comment: And why did you reformat what I helped you format? It is not readable and is missing a } and is actually not making much sense. Can you please create a [mcve]

Comment: sory as U asked, I just wanna mention my array related codes only. I only gave you the part where I wanna check the condition

Comment: Use date.getTime() to get an INT and then add 24*60*60*1000 to it per day

Comment: If change Like dis, Did it take too time to check for each day for one year?

Comment: a better way is to get the selected range using the tools provided by fullcalendar

Comment: I found this: `calendar.component.props.eventSources["0"]._raw`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as @mplungjan commented.

```
var arr = [];
var date = new Date('01-01-2019');
var DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

var day1 = date.getTime();

var day365 = day1+ 365*DAY;

var iDay = day1;

while(iDay < day365){
    // pushing the value in arr for example.
    arr.push(new Date(iDay));

    // do your logic

    iDay = iDay + DAY;
}
```

Comment: Only push the dates that are selected in the calendar

Comment: Sir, from your code- day1 is set as todays date right? but I want to set day 1 as Jan 1,2019 to day 365 as dec 31,2019...

Comment: sry sir, In this Method, I cant able to check my conditions inside loop as date changed to gettime(). now I used `var date=new date(year,0,1)`, this one statisfies my condition, so Is there any way to add next next day to my date?

Comment: Can you explain clearly? why cant you check you conditions inside loop?

Comment: I want to check my calendar's selected color or text for selected year, so if  I change day to daytime, I cant able to include my calendar in my condition

Answer (score -1):

You can use [daysInMonth](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/) function of moment.js to find how many days in each month. After that you can create your array.

```
var dates = [];
var year = new Date().getFullYear(); 
for (var i = 1, l = 12; i <= l; i++){ 
    var daysInMonth = moment("2012-" + i, "YYYY-M").daysInMonth();
    console.log("month : " + i)
    console.log("days in month : " + daysInMonth)  
    for (i1 = 1, l1 = daysInMonth; i1 <= l1; i1++) {
        dates.push(year + "-" + i + "-" + i1)
    }
}
console.log(dates);
```